# carbonated ginger hydromel

Tags: carbonation

I want to make a carbonated ginger hydromel. this is my first batch of mead. Im confused about the use of Campden tablets. If I use these to protect against nasty things happening due to the raw ginger (not even sure if this is a risk) will they stop fermentation?
thank you

Answer (score 3):

Campden tablets will not stop fermentation, they will help drive out Chlorides from tap water at 1 tab/100l, and at higher levels they will protect against unwanted bacteria and some wild yeasts.